# Bootstrap SASS Override primary button text color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I am trying to use sass to set the **text color** of `btn-primary` to white from it's default grey.

I can see by looking at the default **_buttons.scss** file that the variable used to set the color is `$body-color` but if I change this variable to white then obviously all body text also becomes white on a white background.

I have tried just manually setting the color of `.btn`, but then hovering sets the text back to grey. As Below:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.btn {
    color: #fff;
}
```

How can I override this style?

Comment: This helps you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 0):

you can easily change only the button color using the button-variant mixins. Since you only want to change the button color, and not the entire primary theme color, you need to use the button-variant mixins in SASS.

```
$mynewcolor:teal;

.btn{
    @include button-variant($mynewcolor);
}
```

Comment: this did not work